# Angular 2 and render sibling element

Tags: angular

I am in the process of rewriting an Angular 1 grid I wrote in Angular 2.  One of the features the grid has is the ability to expand a row (tr) to view details.  The way I did it in Angular 1 was to put an attribute directive on the tr.  this directive would create a new tr with $compile and insert it after the tr before it.  When the button on the first tr was clicked, then the one below it would show up.  I have been trying to figure out how to do this in angular 2 for a while and have run out of ideas.  I have figured out how to render a component dynamically inside of another but not as a sibling.  I Was hoping anybody could at least point me in the right direction. Here is the general idea of what I did in Angular 1.  the row in the ng-if is the row from tr before this one:

```
      template = '<tr class="cs-grid-detail-row" ng-if="row.isExpanded"><td colspan="' + (colCount || tds.length) + '"><' + component + ' data="data"></' + component + '></td></tr>';
      tr.after($compile(template)(scope));
```

Answer (score 0):

Once I actually understood ViewContainerRef and that it creates the component as a sibling it turned out to be quite easy so wanted to share.  I started by creating a component for my grid row with the selector of tr[grid-row].  Inside that component in the ngOnInit I did this:

```
 this.resolver.resolveComponent(this.row.component).then(factory=>{
        const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders([], this.vcRef.parentInjector);
        var cmp = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory, 0, injector, []);
        cmp.instance.colCount = this.columns.length + 1;
        cmp.instance.row = this.row;

    });
```

Of course for this to render correctly the template of the component that you resolve has to be wrapped in a tr and td.  the td is why I pass in the column count so that is can do colspan.